# Type URL and show HTTP status

Tags: shell-script, awk, wget, http, url

I want to make a shell script where I type an url and it returns me the status code.So far I've tested `wget` is there any other cause it has the tendency to save whatever you run. Then I tried to some kind `awk` the output but it doesn't do you have any advices.

---

Edit for Zelda:
I tried the first one

[image]

but I always receive :
[image]

P.S. Also I tried HTTP without '',now I putted for curiosity

Comment: You left out `2>&1` from the `wget ...` line, that makes the output to stderr go to the pipe and `grep`. Quotes around HTTP not needed.

Comment: Oops, thx very much now it works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply use `curl` for it. I have written a simple script for it.

```
url=$1
curl -sL $url -w "%{http_code} %{url_effective}\\n" "URL" -o /dev/null
```

Where URL is your URL which you have to test output will gives you status.

Example

[image: image showing status for URL]

Answer (score 4):

You can just stick with `wget`:

```
wget -O /dev/null http://unix.stackexchange.com 2>&1 | grep -F HTTP
```

that gives you:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

which you can further trim with `cut`:

```
wget -O /dev/null http://unix.stackexchange.com 2>&1 | grep -F HTTP | cut -d ' ' -f 6
```

If the url does not exist, then there is no output.

With query for url:

```
echo "give your url"
read url
wget -O /dev/null $url 2>&1 | grep -F HTTP
echo "ok?"
```